# What were the Kingpin's plans for Spider-Man?

Tags: marvel, spider-man

In an issue of Spectacular Spider-Man in the Birth of Venom collection, A lieutenant of the Kingpin called the Rose puts a contract on Spider-Man's life. In a later issue when the Kingpin learns of this he claims to "have other plans for Spider-Man"- plans which seem to require Spider-Man alive, as he orders the Rose to call off the hit.

Does anyone know what the Kingpin had in store for Spider-Man?